# Evaluate $\int_{0}^{1} \log^2(x)\log^2(1-x)\,dx$ using non-elementary methods.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, sequences-and-series, analysis

The task is to evaluate, **using the specific given hint, and only real-analysis methods, no complex analysis is allowed in the problem.**
$$\int_0^1 \log^2(x)\log^2(1-x)\, dx$$
The hint given is:
$$ \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (H_k)(x^k) = (-)\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x},$$
where $H_k$ is the harmonic number.

If we integrate both sides we get. 
$$ (2)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(H_k)(x^{k+1})}{(k+1)} = \log^2(1-x)$$
Recalling the hint:
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (H_k)(x^k) = (-)\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}$$
Substitute $x \to 1-x$
$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (H_k)((1-x)^k) = \frac{-\log(x)}{x}$$
Integrate both sides to get:
$$(2)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (H_k)\frac{((1-x)^{k+1})}{k+1} = \log^2(x)$$

I think it is a good idea to evaluate the sums differently.

Or simply,
$$\log^2(x)\log^2(1-x) = \left[(2)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (H_k)\frac{((1-x)^{k+1})}{k+1}\right]\left[(2)\cdot\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{(H_k)(x^{k+1})}{(k+1)}\right]$$

But that would result in quadruple sums... Any ideas?

Comment: @M.N.C.E. close but in this I give the specific sum hint, along with the only method being Real Analysis.